# Asp.net web routing. Same url pattern without any constraints

Tags: asp.net, routes

Hi every one i am working on asp.net web routing. I need same url pattern without any constraints.

i need following multiple URL pattern.

```
 "CountryRoute","{country_name}" "~/country.aspx" => www.abc.com/australia/

 "PageRoute","{page_url}" "~/page.aspx" => www.abc.com/contact_us/

 "keywordRoute","{keyword_url}" "~/keyword.aspx" => www.abc.com/keywordName/
```

i can't apply any constraints.

Comment: There are several ways of doing stuff like this without "constraints", e.g. your own RouteBase derived class, IRouteHandler etc., but I don't understant fully what you want - can you clarify? How do you intend to separate e.g. the possible keyword "australia" from the possible country "australia"? Why is constraints not an option? You will have to validate the input to determine what is what in any case.

Comment: for example i have two routes like
www.domainname.com/australia this link goes to page on which description of australia country showing and also have other link like
www.domainname.com/australia this link goes to a page where we show all products of australia.
Both link going to different destination page but URL are same. so i can't apply any constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have one common URL for two different resources (without magic, that is). That's like suggesting one road could take you to two different places.

You know that en URL is kind of the address of a web page, right? Consider the similar properties in comparison with a real address of a real house; It would be OK to have two addresses for one house, but if two different houses had the same address (in the same town, county, country etc.) then how would the postman be able to tell which house a certain letter should be delivered to?

If you wanted to, you could build your own route handling but that wouldn't change the fact that at one point or another you need to do the job of the postman and identify some unique feature of the request or its context, that points towards one resource or the other. It could be the querystring, a session object, whether the call was made from a computer i China or Germany or whatever -- you need to decide what makes sense in your case. "Both link going to different destination page but URL are same", as you wrote in your answer to my comment, does not.